# What design pattern is this? It has to do with threads

Tags: multithreading, oop, design-patterns, memory-management

Forgive me if I've missed an obvious answer, but I have looked around for this and I cannot find it.  I am trying to build a multi-threaded program that uses mutexes as little as possible.  The following is the basic design.  I want to know if I'm recreating the wheel and, if I am, what design pattern/algorithm/approach am I unwittingly borrowing from?

I have a global object that is basically a message queue for a bunch of threads.  Every time a thread is created it gets a function to which it submits messages.  Only the thread can access the function.  When a message is submitted to the function, the object takes the message and puts it into a queue.

This is a FIFO queue that basically works as shared memory for inter-thread communication.  The thing is, only the global object can add or delete messages.  Every thread regularly checks the queue.  Every time it finds a message it can use, it copies the message to itself and then signals the global object that it's read the data.  If a thread looks at the message and doesn't need it, then it still signals that it has read the message, but it doesn't copy it.  When every thread has looked at the data, the global object deletes the message.

That's it.  It's basic.  It eats up memory.  It's just meant to avoid locking variables, etc.

Comment: If you think about this carefully, you'll find that you need some sort of synchronisation and atomic variables. How do you "signal that you read the message"? How do you track who has read a message? The devil is in the details.

Comment: +1 for giving a clue in the title what the design pattern is about. This is rare when it comes to questions about design patterns, see the related list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is a message bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus). Don't write one yourself, there is probably a framework in your language.

Answer (score 0):

The operating system term you are looking for is Message Passing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing